# Verificar uma opção do obj json e retornar

Tags: javascript, angular

Boa tarde pessoal.
Estou começando começando agora com angular 2 e estou tendo um problema.
Tenho um objeto json e dentro desse obj, tenho vários inputs e quero filtrar pelas cores que eu  recebo nesse obj.

Exemplo do json:

```
public alerts = [
{      text: 'lorem ipsum', color: 'green'
},
{      text: 'lorem ipsum', color: 'yellow'
},
{      text: 'lorem ipsum', color: 'red'
},
{      text: 'lorem ipsum' }]
```

estou tentando filtrar pelas cores para saber em qual variavel eu vou colocar o retorno. Estou tentando fazer assim:

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.alerts.length; i++) {
  let obj = this.alerts[i];
  console.log(obj)
  if(this.alerts[i].color == 'green'){
    this.normal= this.alerts[i]
  }else{
    this.attention = this.alerts[i]
  }
}
```

Mas não esta funcionando como eu quero, quero separar nessas 2 variaveis, attention e normal, fazendo a verificação. Dizendo que quando a  cor foir "green" o json dela, vai pra variavel normal.

Comment: Do jeito que está, `normal: {"text":"lorem ipsum","color":"green"}` e 
`attention: {"text":"lorem ipsum"}`. O que tem de errado?

Comment: Pq  o template da erro, reclamando que não aceita o array.

Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O **javascript** já fornece a função **[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**:

```
var normal = alerts.filter(function( obj ) {
  return obj.color == "green";
});
```

e para attention:

```
var attention = alerts.filter(function( obj ) {
  return obj.color != "green";
});
```

Comment: isso resolveu, obrigada.